# Meaning of "to go noodle with"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The context is the *Seinfeld* show, in a scene where Kramer proposes the idea of a brassiere for men, that is called a *Bro*:

> JERRY: Boy, that brain never stops working, does it?
>
> KRAMER: I tell you, I'm gonna **go noodle with** this.

I could not find any bit of information clarifying this phrase on the Internet.

Comment: See http://www.dictionaryupdate.com/Noodle.

Comment: It seems that `noodle` is a pretty broad term if consider its all slang meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the context, I think it means, *"I'm gonna go crazy with this!"* Or, perhaps even better: *"I'm gonna go bonkers with this!"*

In this case, *going crazy* (or *going bonkers*, or *going noodle*) means to *go wild*; that is, to **not** do something in moderation. Kramer is essentially telling Jerry: *"I'm telling you, this is going to be huge! This [idea] will catch on like crazy."*

NOAD mentions, under its entry for *crazy*:

> **like crazy** to a great degree : *I was laughing like crazy*.

Comment: I would have said, "laughing like a crazy" because that is the translation in English of what we say in Italian. It's good I don't say that in English. `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno: "Laughing like a crazy" would mean, "laughing like a crazy person." It's not idiomatic, but it would be understood. "Laughing like crazy" simply means, "laughing a lot." One can laugh like crazy, eat like crazy, train like crazy, yell like crazy, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is what the Italian _ridere come un matto/matta_ would mean. We use the article where English would not use it. `:))`

Answer (score 4):

In this usage, it's a synonym for "fiddle" or "tinker".

per [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/noodle?s=t):

> to play; toy: *to noodle with numbers as a hobby.*

It needs to be parsed as (I am going to go) ([and] noodle (with this)).

Comment: As the OALD says, "In spoken English _go_ can be used with _and_ plus another verb to show purpose or to tell somebody what to do": _Go and get me a drink!_

Comment: @kiamlaluno: You can also leave out the _"and"_ in many cases: _Go get me a drink!_